# dots with-in pagination using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, pagination

I need a small help in achieving the pagination using pure javascript.

We wrote this function to do so which will also give me the options for the pagination options to be rendered with-in FE.

```
paginateData: function (items, page, per_page) {

        var page = page || 1,
            per_page = per_page || 25,
            offset = (page - 1) * per_page,

            paginatedItems = items.slice(offset).slice(0, per_page),
            total_pages = Math.ceil(items.length / per_page),
            pageList = new Set(),
            ix = 0;
        for (var i = page; i <= total_pages; i++) {

            if (ix < 3 || ix === (total_pages-page)) {
                pageList.add(i.toString());
            } else {
                pageList.add("...");
            }
            ix++;
        }
        return {
            page: page,
            per_page: per_page,
            pre_page: page - 1 ? page - 1 : null,
            next_page: (total_pages > page) ? page + 1 : null,
            total: items.length,
            total_pages: total_pages,
            data: paginatedItems,
            pageOptions: pageList,
        };
    }
```

I need output of pageOptions as below for given scenarios:

a) Total Pages are 10 and page is 1:
["1", "2", "3", "...", "10"]

b) Total Pages are 10 and page is 2:
["1", "2", "3", "...", "10"]

c) Total Pages are 10 and page is 3:
["1", "2", "3", "...", "10"]

d) Total Pages are 10 and page is 4:
["1", "2", "3", "4", "...", "10"]

e) Total Pages are 10 and page is 5:
["1", "...",  "4", "5", "6", "...", "10"]

f) Total Pages are 10 and page is 6:
["1", "...",  "5", "6", "7", "...", "10"]

g) Total Pages are 10 and page is 7:
["1", "...", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]

h) Total Pages are 10 and page is 8:
["1", "...", "7", "8", "9", "10"]

i) Total Pages are 10 and page is 9:
["1", "...", "8", "9", "10"]

j) Total Pages are 10 and page is 10:
["1", "...", "8", "9", "10"]

Comment: Can you provide all the scenarios when page selection is 1 to 9? Will help in assisting you better.

Comment: Total Pages are 9 and page is 1: ["1", "2", "3", "...", "9"] - it is working.
Total Pages are 9 and page is 2: ["2", "3", "4", "...", "9"] - it is working.

Comment: All your scenarios are still not clear. For eg, if page is 5 should it be [1, ..., 4, 5, 6, ..., 9] or [1, ..., 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]. Similarly, if page is 3, do you want [1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 9] or [3, 4, 5, ..., 9]? All this will only be clear if you give us a list of all your required outputs when page is 1 to 9.

Comment: Added all the outputs needed for different scenarios

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you.

```
//When first or second page is selected
if(page <= 2){
    pageList.add(1.toString());
    pageList.add(2.toString());
    pageList.add(3.toString());
    pageList.add("...");
    pageList.add(total_pages.toString());
}

//When second last or last page is selected
else if(page > total_pages-2){
    pageList.add(1.toString());
    pageList.add("...");
    pageList.add(total_pages-2.toString());
    pageList.add(total_pages-1.toString());
    pageList.add(total_pages.toString());
}
else{
    pageList.add(1.toString());
    if(page-2 > 1){
        pageList.add("...");
    }
    pageList.add((page-1).toString());
    pageList.add(page.toString());
    pageList.add((page+1).toString());
    if(page+2 < total_pages){
        pageList.add("...");
    }               
    pageList.add(total_pages.toString());
}
```

Below scenarios are modified to be more consistent with other scenarios

c) Total Pages are 10 and page is 3: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "...", "10"]

d) Total Pages are 10 and page is 4: ["1", "...", "3", "4", "5", "...", "10"]

g) Total Pages are 10 and page is 7: ["1", "...", "6", "7", "8", "...", "10"]